# Blazor Server: OnAfterRender not called on manual browser refresh

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor server app is running in debug mode in VS 2019 on IIS Express.

I have a component, HoursRegistration.razor, with this page declaration:

```
@page "/hoursregistration/"
@page "/hoursregistration/{SelectedJobCardID:int}"
```

When I link to this page with the parameter, it is rendered as expected.

```
https://localhost:44380/hoursregistration/2
```

However, when I refresh the page using the browser refresh button, only *OnInitialized* is called, not *OnAfterRender*, and the rendering fails. This only happens when the parameter is set. Without the parameter, browser refresh works fine.

Can anyone help explaining what is going on here?

Comment: [Polite] Not correct, both will be called unless there's something you're not telling us!  And Render can't fail as the component has already rendered before "OnAfterRender" is called! More code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found out that I had forgot to add

```
<base href="~/" />
```

to _Host.cshtml